# How to determine smallest width of android device

Tags: android

I am new to the concepts of android layouts associated with different screen sizes. I wish to make a different layout for a tab which is of 8" and place it in a "layout-swxxxx" folder. And have another generic layout for tabs bigger than than 8" in "layout" folder.

Here is the configuration of my 8" tablet.
Screen size 8.0 inches
Resolution 1200 x 1920 pixels (~283 ppi pixel density)

Can anyone tell me how to calculate the "sw", so that i can name my layout folder accordingly.

Also I don't have the physical device with me so its not possible for me to find this value with any code. So request an alternative method.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The formula linking dp, pixels and density is as follow :

> px = dp * (dpi / 160)

Therefore, in your case,

```
widthInDp = widthInPx / (dpi / 160)
widthInDp = 1200 / (283 / 160)
widthInDp = ~678dp
```

So you're gonna want to use a bucket such as sw600dp

Reference : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Using this formula i tried to calculate Width in dp for another tab (1200 x 1920 ~224 ppi). I got the width as ~857. But this tab seems to pick the layout from layout-sw480dp. I do not understand the behavior. Could you please help me understand

Comment: What you need is to create a layout directory sw857dp (or even sw850dp), so that the device will grab the layouts from there, rather than sw480dp. Remember, sw480dp means "if the device has at least a screen width of 480 AND there isn't a folder closer to the device's actual SW, use sw480dp".

Comment: @FractalBob Using the above calculation,  The smallest width of Huawei MediaPad T3 (8 inch tablet)  is 533. The device configuration of the device is (600 x 1280 ~240 ppi). This is actually less than 600. How do i make this device to support Tablet layout?