# Android: Navigation drawer on tablets

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

According to the [Material Design documentation](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/android), there is a "standard" and a "modal" version of the navigation drawer. The former is meant for tablets and the later is meant for smart phones.

I have an app, which uses a drawer to switch between several fragments, and since most fragments only contain simple lists, I would like to show both the open drawer and the visible fragment on tablets.

I have read a dozen similar questions here on SO, but all of them were years old, so I ping this topic again. **Is there a built in, automatic way to switch between the standard and modal state depending on the screen size without messing too much with the source code?**

Since Google pushes app compatibility on various devices, I expect them to have a solution which, even with alternative layouts, but can utilize the built in drawer handling implementation. Although, I have found nothing in the official documentations.

Comment: So what approaches you've tried so far?

Comment: @SamChen Nothing so far, besides running the project on a tablet emulator. I had a slight hope that it would work automatically.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a built in, automatic way to switch between the standard and modal state depending on the screen size without messing too much with the source code?

Actually, yes.

1. Create Layout resource file -> select "Smallest Screen Width" in "Available qualifiers" -> click ">>" and type in 600 -> "OK".
2. Determine whether to lock the **Drawer** in each Layout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50646711/3466808

---

- Why 600dp for tablet devide:
  [How to determine smallest width of android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36692756/how-to-determine-smallest-width-of-android-device)

Comment: I am trying to implement this solution, but it requires me to massively mess up my `MainActivity`, which is exactly what I wanted to avoid.